# Navigate to another screen in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, push

Below is the code i am trying to push to another swiftUI when button in swiftUI is pressed.
But it is not navigating to another screen

```
  let controller = DestinationHostingController(rootView: AnotherSwiftUI())
  pushViewController(controller, animated: animated)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is because it is not SwiftUI code. You should go through [Apple's SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) and
[Stanford's CS193P](https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu).

Answer (score 1):

In SwiftUI, the navigation has been improved,
You have to embed your view inside a NavigationView,
and after that you can use NavigationLink to redirect wherever you want

example:

```js
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack(spacing: 30) {
                Text("You're going to flip a coin – do you want to choose heads or tails?")

                NavigationLink(destination: ResultView(choice: "Heads")) {
                    Text("Choose Heads")
                }

                NavigationLink(destination: ResultView(choice: "Tails")) {
                    Text("Choose Tails")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation")
        }
    }
}
```

(You can replace the NavigationLink content by whatever you want, Text -> Button)